# SharePoint 2013 drop down menu separator/horizontal rule

Tags: 2013, dropdown, formatting

I am trying to add separators (hr/) in the drop down menus of my SharePoint, however I am unable to find the place to do it within the master page. I have inspected the page in both Google Chrome and Internet Explorer and found where it should go, but those places don't show up in the master page for whatever reason. Does anyone have a solution or another way to add these separators? I have added a picture showing what I want but it was done through Developer tools.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following CSS to your master page:

```
li.dynamic {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px;
}

li.dynamic:first-child {
    padding-top: 0px;
}

li.dynamic:last-child {
    border: none;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```